# Display string item in windows - C#

Tags: c#

I have a string with dots and carriage returns etc... totally its a big string!
I want to show it in a windows form, so i wanted to know which one will be the good control to show it upon.

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Comment: "dots"?  What do you mean by that?  Do you mean full stops, or do you mean control characters?

Answer (score 3):

Use a TextBox with the Multiline property set to True.

Alternatively you can use a RichTextBox control or a WebBrowser control where you set the DocumentText property.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) for displaying the plain text.  Check out the [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) method.